# How to use selector and methods in Page Object Model in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

I have problem with this code in Cypress. When I run my test with function 'checkOperations()' I receive such a message:
'Cannot read property 'should' of undefined'

I use Page Object Model:

```
// my selectors
save(){
    cy.get('.text-right > .btn-success')
}

back(){
    cy.get('#isDirtyId_return_button')
}

// my methods
  checkOperations(){
    this.save().should('contain', 'Save').and('be.visible')
    this.back().should('contain', 'Back').and('be.visible')
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: are you defining the selector functions in a different js file or the same file as your tests ?

Comment: I would suggest using TypeScript to detect many problems (including this one) automatically

Answer (score 2):

I think you just missed the `return`

```js
// my selectors
save(){
  return cy.get('.text-right > .btn-success')
}

back(){
  return cy.get('#isDirtyId_return_button')
}

// my methods
  checkOperations(){
    this.save().should('contain', 'Save').and('be.visible')
    this.back().should('contain', 'Back').and('be.visible')
}
```

Also, if the buttons always have that text separating the static features from the dynamic features feels better

```js
// my selectors
save(){
  return cy.get('.text-right > .btn-success').should('contain', 'Save')
}

back(){
  return cy.get('#isDirtyId_return_button').should('contain', 'Back')
}

// my methods
  checkOperations(){
    this.save().should('be.visible')
    this.back().should('be.visible')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found the solution. I need to add 'return' ;)

```
// my selectors
       save(){
            return cy.get('.text-right > .btn-success')}
       back(){
            return cy.get('#isDirtyId_return_button')}

// my methods
       checkOperations(){
            this.save().should('contain', 'Save').and('be.visible')
            this.back().should('contain', 'Back').and('be.visible')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   // my methods
 checkOperations(){
   this.save().contains('Save').should('be.visible')
   this.back().contains('Back').should('be.visible')
 }
```

Comment: That aint work. Now I get 'Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined'